# In Bootstrap JS Modal, how to make Submit button only visible for mobile application

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented Bootstrap JS Modal tutorial,
as given in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal2&stacked=h
login button is visible for both desktop and mobile application.
How to make it visible only for mobile application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use class `hidden-lg hidden-md`

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg hidden-lg hidden-md" id="myBtn">Login</button>
```

[Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)